# What is the difference between vuejs and vue native?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-native

I am trying to move to the vuejs and currently trying to learn it. All I ended up in confusion only. Can you guys tell me what is the difference between them? Are these both similar or completely different with regards to syntax or anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Vue.js is for building SPA web applications. Vue Native is for building native mobile apps.